# Accesstoken not available after reopening website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC 3 website with the Facebook C# SDK. 
Now i'm redoing the facebook integration in a clean MVC 4 application with the new version 6 of the sdk. So I used the gettings started help page on the sdk website. http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started

I've followed the tutorial and changed only one part of the tutorial. The thing that I changed was that I call an Controller Action because the ashx was fired but wasn't allowed to set the accesstoken in the Session object. The Session was null.

Now when I start the website for the first time (used Chrome because IE won't work by default. The tutorial explains why.), I see the login button.
When I press the login button, I get the authorize page of facebook that asks that my app wants to connect to my facebook account. When I submit, the MVC action in the controller gets fired and the given accesstoken is stored in the session.
After that I can access my own information.

When I close Visual Studio (IIS express is closed with it) and restart the website, the login button is changed to my account with picture that says that I use the app that is connected. After that I navigate back to the page with my own information and get a nullreferenceexception on the session that gets the accesstoken. Why is that? Why is the user logged in but the action that stores the accesstoken isn't fired the second time that I open the website (new session).

Shouldn't I set the app secret somewhere? I have set the AppId in the javascript following the  tutorial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per Facebook your user is logged into your app, but since you restarted your Cassini web server, your "session" is gone/lost/deleted.

Check your session to ensure you have a valid token, in session, if not redirect the user to your login code.

Comment: I know that the session is lost so the accestoken isn't in the session anymore. But why won't I see the login button then but instead of that I see my own name and a small profile picture... Now I can't login so the accestoken code to store it could not get fired

Comment: Facebook maintains it's own state, which is not necessarily the same as the state in your webserver's session.  If you want them to match, then you should call FB.logout() to get rid of the client's cookie that is making the picture show up.

Comment: Hmmm I see that there is a difference between the IE facebook session and the chrome session because when I logout in IE, and open chrome, I'm still loggedin in Facebook. When I logout in Chrome and start my app in chrome, I don't see the picture anymore but the login button isn't there as well? I do see the 4 loading blocks of facebook on the place where the login button should be.

Comment: I now understand why the login button is in the tutorial. It is only needed to connect your app with facebook. And when your loggedin in Facebook, your name and picture is visible. When your not logged in facebook, you don't see a thing. So it has nothing todo with getting a accesstoken when opening the site but only the first time when you connected your app as a redirect so you could directly show some information of the user...